# How to print a whole collection without using an explicit iterator, loop or recursion in Java

Tags: java, collections

Sorry if my question isn't as difficult as I'm making it out to be, I'm just getting back into Java programming and need to remember A LOT. Thanks in advance for any and all help. The code that I have so far looks like:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class New {

    Collection<String> names= Arrays.asList("Dave", "Alan", "Brock");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    private void printCollection(Collection<String> collection) {


    }
```

As in, I want to print the names separated by commas. Thanks again!

Comment: Is there a specific reason to avoid looping over it?  Was this an interview question?

Comment: most reasonable collections override `toString()`. Why not just `System.out.println(collection)` ?

Comment: checkout apache Commons Lang and use the method StringUtils.join(...).
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Comment: No matter *what* you do, there's a loop written by someone, somewhere, and it's getting used.

Comment: Your question sounds like one asked by an experienced java expert, especially the "explicit iterator". Is this a test question?

Comment: @scrappedcola - or Guava Joiner (see below)

Answer (score 1):

Although internally it uses a loop, in the user-code, you could do

```
System.out.println(names);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(names);
```

This works for all objects inside the collection that have overriden its `toString()` method, which is true for many built-in java classes.                                            .

Answer (score -1):

There *will* be a loop, whether it's explicit or hidden behind a API. e.g. using Guava

```
String s = Joiner.on(",").join(names);
```

will give you a string of elements separated by commas, which you can then print using `System.out.println()` etc. Note this is more customisable than the usual printable `Collection`, since you can provide a separator of your own choice.

You don't have an *explicit* loop, but there is one under the covers.